# 404 error page when deploy wordpress site from local server to live server

Tags: php, database, wordpress, ftp, cpanel

I have a Question about deploy website from a Local serve to a live server.
I started (and finished) to build a WordPress site locally on my computer, with a theme framework. simple.
I moved all the files from the Local server to the live server cpannel,
(Databace files, website files and replacing URLs).
The home page opens as usual but When I tried to open each sub-page on the site - 404 error page had occured.
I do not have the original files on my local computer because fortunately my computer crashed. Yeay. 
Does anyone knows what to do given the particular situation?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Most likely cause is either URLs haven't been updated correctly in the database or permalinks need to be flushed. If after you've checked all that you still have an issue I'd look at whether you have mod_rewrite enabled.

Answer (score 0):

This could be because of a few reasons. To avoid this from happening, migrate the site to the live server with a plugin like "[duplicator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator)" for example.